# Tensorflow 1.12 different results than Tensorflow 2.4

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to upgrade my model to tensorflow 2.4 but the network achieves lower accuracy after upgrade. I noticed that loss function for a single batch is different even though:

- I use `model = keras.models.load_model('path/to/model.h5')` with the same path for both versions (this file was created using tf 1.12)
- I check that weights match
- I check that batch used is the same
- I replicated this problem on both proprietary dataset and `keras.datasets.mnist`.

I expect that if I manage to achieve the same loss on both versions I will also achieve the same accuracy after training.

Requirements tf 1.12 version

```
# python version == 3.6
tensorflow_gpu==1.12
keras==2.2.4
h5py==2.10.0
opencv-python==4.2.0.34
```

Requirements tf 2.4.1

```
# python version == 3.8
tensorflow==2.4.1
h5py==2.10.0
opencv-python==4.5.3.56
```

Model definition (this is the same in both versions):

```
def mobile_net(no_classes):
    base = MobileNetV2(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(224, 224, 3))
    for layer in base.layers:
        layer.trainable = False

    x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(base.output)
    x = Dense(32, activation='relu')(x)
    x = Dense(128, activation='relu')(x)

    y = GlobalMaxPooling2D()(base.output)
    y = Dense(32, activation='relu')(y)
    y = Dense(128, activation='relu')(y)

    conc = Add()([x, y])
    conc = Dense(32, activation='relu')(conc)

    prediction = Dense(no_classes, activation='softmax')(conc)
    model = Model(inputs=base.input, outputs=prediction)
    optimizer = Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=None, decay=0.0, amsgrad=False)
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model
```

train method (almost the same in both versions):

```
keras.backend.set_image_dim_ordering('tf')  # only in tf 1.12

# load data
x_train, y_train = ...
x_train, y_train = x_train[:4], y_train[:4]  # select just one batch for testing purposes


model = keras.models.load_model('path/to/model.h5')  # in tf 1.12
model = tensorflow.keras.models.load_model('path/to/model.h5')  # in tf 2.4
print(f'check that the values are the same: {x_train.sum() + y_train.argmax(axis=1).sum()}')
weights = model.get_weights()
print(f'check that weights are the same: {[weight.sum() for weight in weights]}')
model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=4, verbose=2)
```

tf 1.12 output:

> check that the values are the same: 18266047
> check that weights are the same: [-4.311309, 37.386337, 26.299068, ..., -10.376889, 0.0, -13.127711, 0.0, 4.9316425, 0.0]
> Epoch 1/1
>
> - 18s - loss: 2.6805 - acc: 0.2500

tf 2.4 output:

> check that the values are the same: 18266047
> check that weights are the same: [-4.311309, 37.386337, 26.299068, ..., -10.376889, 0.0, -13.127711, 0.0, 4.9316425, 0.0]
> 1/1 - 6s - loss: 2.8985 - accuracy: 0.2500

Where does this difference in loss come from?

Comment: Probably cause you have not set the same seed value across both runs.

Comment: @yudhiesh the runs return the same values as long as I don't change versions. Anyway where would randomness come from? Weights are set, the batch is set and adam optimizer is not stochastic itself as far as I know (also it has no influence on the first batch loss in the training).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This difference comes from the fact that MobileNet contains BatchNormalization layers. Their behaviour changed in Tensorflow 2.x. You can read more [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/transfer_learning#important_note_about_batchnormalization_layers). To recreate Tensorflow 1.x behaviour of BatchNormalization layers I added the following fragment to the model creation code.

```
def mobile_net(no_classes):
    base = MobileNetV2(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(224, 224, 3))
    ### changed in Tensorflow 2.4.1
    for layer in base.layers:
        if layer.__class__ == BatchNormalization:
            layer.trainable = True
        else:
            layer.trainable = False
    ### end of change

    x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(base.output)
    x = Dense(32, activation='relu')(x)
    x = Dense(128, activation='relu')(x)

    y = GlobalMaxPooling2D()(base.output)
    y = Dense(32, activation='relu')(y)
    y = Dense(128, activation='relu')(y)

    conc = Add()([x, y])
    conc = Dense(32, activation='relu')(conc)

    prediction = Dense(no_classes, activation='softmax')(conc)
    model = Model(inputs=base.input, outputs=prediction)
    optimizer = Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=None, decay=0.0, amsgrad=False)
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model
```

The model now returns the same loss both on tf 1.12 and 2.4.1.